# react native splash page logged in user redirect with redux data

Tags: react-native

This is code is in my splash page to autologin a user from previous jwt token, it uses redux, it works except the data is delayed a second or two...

I would like to refactor to :

-- only redirect to TabNavigator once the user data this.props.getUser(token) is valid and ready.

```
async _login() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token > '') {
        const user = await this.props.getUser(token);
        this.redirectScreen('TabNavigator');
    } else {
        this.redirectScreen('Login');
    }
}
```

code:
https://gist.github.com/andraskende/370d64f19bb9c4ab830cfb537c21b439

Comment: Look like you forget to check `user` after `const user = await this.props.getUser(token)`

Comment: Like `if(user && user.token) { //redirect to login}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, this.props.getUser(token) just comes later so even with with await its not yet available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.getUser` dispatches a redux action. It will not return the user object for you. I can think of 2 options for your requirement:

**Option 1 - Do the redirection in middleware**

- Enable navigation from anywhere in the app by following this guide
  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html
- Dispatch the action and do nothing like below:

  ```
  async _login() {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      if(token > '') {
          this.props.getUser(token);
      } else {
          this.redirectScreen('Login');
      }
  }
  ```
- When you handle your `getUser` action in a middleware (maybe a thunk), do the redirection there using the guide in step 1.

  NOTE: maybe you can pass `this.props.navigation` as a payload with the `getUser` action and use it in your middleware instead. But I haven't tried it, and cannot confirm it works.

**Option 2 - Use componentWillReceiveProps**

- Just like in first option, dispatch the redux action:

  ```
  async _login() {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      if(token > '') {
          this.props.getUser(token);
      } else {
          this.redirectScreen('Login');
      }
  }
  ```
- You already subscribed to `state.user`. So, do the redirection when it's updated (provided that you updated it as part of `getUser` actions logic). You can use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

  ```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const oldUserProp = this.props.user || {};
    const newUserProp = nextProps.user;

    // You might need more validation here
    if (!oldUserProp.userId && newUserProp.userId) {
      this.redirectScreen('TabNavigator');
    }
  }
  ```

  NOTE: There is a new lifecycle method called `getDerivedStateFromProps` available. You might want to check that too.

I recommend **Option 1** as it is more predictable.

I also noticed that you reset the router state. You might want to use `SwitchNavigation` for this use case. There is a guide for implementing auth flows in react-navigation documentation. Please read https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html.